# MS SQL How to read the log entry?

Tags: sql-server

How to read `MS SQL` the journal login information?

I've tried the below, but I'm unable to find login info:

```
select * from ::fn_dblog( default, default )
```

Comment: This might help - http://rusanu.com/2014/03/10/how-to-read-and-interpret-the-sql-server-log/

Comment: @Joe C I see  **insert** and **delete** information. Is log contain **select** operations?

Comment: Login details,select details won't be stored in Transaction log

Comment: What @Gameiswar says makes sense.  I have never had to dig into the transaction log myself but it is designed to bring a database back to a point in time and logins or selects do not directly impact that.  (just what is stored, for example, in query stats and auditing tables)  You should look into query DMV's and setting up security auditing.